# How to enable C Syntax Highlighting in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I can't get the C Syntax Highlighting in VSCode to work.
I have installed the C/C++ Extension.
When I set the language mode of a C-File to C++ everything seems to work fine.
But when I set it to C-Mode the standard C keywords seem not to be recognized.

[Syntax Highlighting in C-Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY2yy.png)

[Syntax Highlighting in Cpp-Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TpiL.png)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: The C/C++ extension from Microsoft works for me. Maybe this thread helps https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1305

Comment: I have a similar setup and also using the C/C++ extension. I have a project with mixed C and C++ code and the syntax highlighting switches automatically for .c and .cpp files. Maybe there is another extension fighting for it or you have a custom setting regarding filetypes?

Comment: You might try using some other editor, such as [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/). On my computers, it is syntax-highlighting out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem. I had another extension "Better C Syntax" installed which seems to cause the problem. Uninstalling it solved the problem for me.